# I'm trying to use as.character() in gsub function to replace "alpha" with the symbol 'α' in R

Tags: r

```
    if((grep("alpha",userinput,fixed = TRUE))){
        userinput<- gsub("alpha|Alpha",as.character("\U03B1"),userinput)
      }
```

this prints "Î±" instead of "α". And using

```
userinput<- gsub("alpha|Alpha","α",userinput)
```

prints "a". What can I do to get "α".

Comment: Is `userinput = "alpha"`? Could you include it in your example? I'm getting something like **"Î±"** instead of **"α"**.

Comment: Yes the user input could be anything like helloalphaworld and the output should be helloαworld. But my output is "helloÎ±world". I tried storing as.character("\U03B1") in a variable and using that variable in gsub which is giving the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you set the encoding manually:

```
userinput <- "mm is such an alpha male !!!"
x <- gsub("alpha|Alpha","\u03B1",userinput)
x
# [1] "mm is such an Î± male !!!"
Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"
x
# [1] "mm is such an α male !!!"
```

You would think that setting the encoding on `userinput` would be enough but it isn't, `gsub` has no respect.

When dealing with encoding hell, control the encoding of every input and variable at every step and don't trust anyone. I personally had horrible problems even with prominent text mining packages.

Answer (score 3):

I can see issue with `gsub` as well. An alternative solution can be to use `stringr::str_replace` as it works for me.

```
library(stringr)

str_replace("My name is alpha", pattern = "alpha|Alpha", as.character("\U03B1"))

#[1] "My name is α"

str_replace("My name is Alpha", pattern = "alpha|Alpha", as.character("\U03B1"))
#[1] "My name is α"
```

Comment: That's cool, `str_replace` changed the encoding from `"unknown"` to `UTF-8`, though it doesn't do it if you don't feed it a special character as a replacement.